# How to type the class with values as keys (as "this" object) and methods in the same class

Tags: typescript

I want to rewrite JS module to TS without changing its structure.

What I have now:

```js
class Row {
  // values are like an object { eur: 10 }
  constructor(values) {
    Object.assign(this, values);
  }

  addRow(row) {
    // row + row method
  }
}

const row1 = new Row({ eur: 10 })
const row2 = new Row({ eur: 30 })

console.log(row1) // -> { eur: 10 }
console.log(row1.addRow(row2)) // -> { eur: 40 }
```

What I'm trying to do but getting a TS error

```
class Row {
  [key: string]: number

  constructor(values: Record<string, number>) {
    // @ts-expect-error "Property 'addRow' of type '(row: Row) => Row' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'number'"
    Object.assign(this, values)
  }

  addRow(row: Row) {
     // return row + row method
  }
}

// Want to use the same way

const row1 = new Row({ eur: 10 })
const row2 = new Row({ eur: 30 })

console.log(row1) // -> { eur: 10 }
console.log(row1.addRow(row2)) // -> { eur: 40 }
```

How to get rid of this typescript error?

Comment: It's problematic, even in the JavaScript code, to do `Object.assign(this, values)` while allowing `values` to be anything -- including something with a completely incompatible `addRows` property. Which is part of the problem with typing it with TypeScript -- TypeScript helps bring rigor to things like that.

Comment: Yeah, I'm already on the way to refactoring so much code because I cannot find a solution. But still want to hear from the community.

Comment: You've said you want to avoid changing its *structure*. Do you mean just at the API level? If so, are the data properties of `Row` instances part of the API? Is there code that does `const row = new Row({ eur: 30}); console.log(row.eur);`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. So many places where code is accessing `row.eur` directly. And the string is dynamic, I have no clue how many times and which string are exactly been accessed in the code. Maybe I could play with regexp to fix all the stuff to be inside some variable, like "values", so it would be accessed with `row.values.eur`, but it wouldn't be a 100% working fix. I don't want to play with JS a lot. That's why this question is there.

And, yes, they are part of the API.

Comment: (Strangely, I don't appear to have ever upvoted the question, which was well-asked. I've done so now because your comment on my answer brought me back to the question and I saw I hadn't. Sorry about that. *This comment will self-destruct in five....four....*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...Maybe I could play with regexp to fix all the stuff to be inside some variable, like "values", so it would be accessed with `row.values.eur`...

Yeah, that's the kind of refactor you might want to do.

With what you have, though, unfortunately I think it's too loose to type properly with TypeScript. You're using the `Row` instance *both* as a bag of key/value pairs *and* as the source of a method (`addRow`). If you suppress the error on `addRow` (and adjust the implementation a bit), with the current version of TypeScript, it works:

```typescript
class Row {
    [key: string]: number;

    constructor(values: Record<string, number>) {
        for (const key in values) {
            if (key !== "addRow") {
                this[key] = values[key];
            }
        }
    }

    // @ts-expect-error ts 2411 - this is incompatible with an index signature
    addRow(row: Record<string, number>) {
        const result = new Row(this);
        for (const key in row) {
            if (key !== "addRow") {
                result[key] = (result[key] ?? 0) + row[key];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}

// Want to use the same way

const row1 = new Row({ eur: 10 });
const row2 = new Row({ eur: 30 });

console.log(row1); // -> { eur: 10 }
console.log(row1.addRow(row2)); // -> { eur: 40 }
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBKD2B3aBvAsAKGt6BtA1gKYCeAXNBAC4BOAlgHYDmAuufQK4C2ARodQNyZMOaMHj0q1dsErxqACgBuYEO0IRysQmOoATADySGjADTQOPPgD4AlKmEicAMznR5YiZWhFi0BtGVVdTt0LEdw2ic3H2gAQgBeeOgAIjBdXQREZJCHcLzoSgALWggCEmZoJMC1Up9mQTD87ABfXMdWxugOtoB6HugAAUoIAFpCAA8AB21KMepqV2HoACYAFgBGdegRguKYEr96MU5JsEpabhBCaERaIugwekPdCYpaRnoz9mpCNrSMpDyBaITTaOQGIxMMwWXjUWz2ToiDxUaA-CDsEBeJL0QjITLyIolGwNfIuahuZFeGL+YE5RF5SLREhxRIpf6ZbIIpp5NEYyhlYgVJJA9R8gUVAD8EugAAY7ABqVFIcUk7ldNoiDr5H6Ub5PXmY1UtTDdDB9aAAdUeXlk0HYEGuRWuEDAnGuiDAxCEGEpSsQW2xuLggJQ0EI33I6xlXWJmF9wOWlXMQfxofD1HIAGZo81Yxg4+IIPArgA6EDwRhApDrYnQc0jKyoMMR6BR9U+wvFwhlitV-0l9mAhM2Wv1xtplurHNAA) (and [here's a version](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBKD2B3aBvAsAKGt6BtA1gKYCeAXNBAC4BOAlgHYDmAuufQK4C2ARodQNyZMOaMHj0q1dsErxqACgB0ygG5gQ7QhHKxCY6gBMAPJIaMANNA48+APlzMAlKmEicAMznR5YiZQrw7NTAhNDw7tBqGlrO6FhuCZ7U3r5U0ETE0AwBQSGxrgmFWRHyGdAAhAC8ldAARGAGBgiItfnxRR3QlAAWtBAEJMzQNRCBwYQDxMyC7Z04AL4FHYuzIitrQrMA9FvQAAKUEAC0hAAeAA56lCfU1F6H0ABMACwAjK-QR129MH1Z9GJOOcwJRaNwQKFELQetAwPR-gYzhRaIx6CCgoQlg0mkh5HdEDo9HJjKYmJZrLxqLY2kVUv5qFp2CB-DV6IRkM15D0+o4ZkUkilxGkytl8TS5rQSmUqjV6o1mq0XKs5gyIEzKJMhjU8YzmZroAB+A3QAAMzgA1NB8Zq+XN1oV7QkGZQgvDVerbdgVitMDtoAB1OH+WTQdgQUI9UIQMCcSFgYibOlWpAfVnsuC4lDQQhBcivE3QeaWLNhgzkR4F+a8zBJ-GPYZWdOcksQMvQZ6V4vZ3PQADMld50D9ADl4JRCOQAJLQc7sYPdLShbJgaAGSXuPiEej+Yl8f7j7e0cTqEAJjA1oXwCGKEDwRh4lODv1HWyobvUPMmyyl8uVi8SK9CBvO8H0QV5FGxTk60cJ9dhfN8cw-dsv1DVtyAANkrIA) accepting multiple parameters in the constructor as your original question did).

**But**, I would hesitate to use that, because I can't say that tomorrow's TypeScript won't handle `addRows` differently (from a type perspective) and complain about the `addRows` calls because it decides that `addRows` is a `number` rather than a method. (That said, if it happens, well, you'll know it happened.)

Some notes on what I did there:

1. I made the constructor and `addRow` accept [`Record<string, number>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) rather than `Row`, so that your object literals will work.
2. I removed `Object.assign` and replaced it with our own loop so we can skip the `addRows` property if there is one.
3. It has that unfortunate `@ts-expect-error` (see caveat above).
4. I used nullish coalescing to add a property to `record` if `row` has it but `this` didn't, using the value `0` in that case.

Comment: I suggest you leave the question open for a day or so. The above functions, but... There are a couple of real TypeScript whizzes around who may be able to offer a better approach, though again it's hard when we can't change the dual nature of the instances.

Comment: Well, no answers anymore ;(